# Referring to the commit prior to a commit specified using `:/` syntax?

Tags: git, git-revision

The most recent commit whose commit message contains "foo" is spelled `:/foo`, as in:

```
git show :/foo
```

How does one refer to the parent of that commit? `:/foo^` is incorrect; that results in:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument ':/foo^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

The only thing I've been able to come up with so far is using the output of `git rev-parse`:

```
git show $(git rev-parse :/foo)^
```

...which works, but seems needlessly complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* `:/foo` finds `HEAD:^{/foo}`, you can put the trailing `^` into the second syntax as `HEAD:^{/foo}^`.  If it finds `xyz:^{/foo}`, you can put the trailing `^` in this way.  But since it might find either of those, or some other such string, there is no one-step syntax for what you want.

The two-step syntax is what is actually used in various Git scripts, though typically it is coded more as:

```
hash=$(git rev-parse "$usersupplied") || exit
hash=$(git rev-parse $hash^) || exit
```

so as to handle errors better.